# How to capture keyboard input in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to capture/save data while writing in a `HTML` form. I am using `HTML`, `php`, `MySQL` and `Javascript`.

I have a registration form having three fields. Suppose an user inputs in those three fields but did not save it. I want to capture all what the user wrote in those three fields/two fields/one fields (whatever he/she wrote).

How could I do this ? I do not know how to start.

***UPDATE***

[image: Diagram should be like this]

Comment: Hook a keypress event to those fields. After a set timeout, say 30 seconds, send an AJAX request with the form data to save the draft form to the database, or keep it in localstorage depending on the data model you want to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Use contenteditable property of table.

JS

```js
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {       
   $.ajax({
    url: "pTedit/saveedit.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
    success: function(data){
     $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
    }        
     });
  }
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'columnName','<?php echo $getData["id"]; ?>')">data</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in saveedit.php

`//DB connection string
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE tableName SET " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);`

Try this it may help

Comment: Hi Vivek, I've tried it..... it is editing the content of a `table data` or `div`. I want to save data from a `HTML form` while typing into the element of it without submitting the `form` and **without informing the user**.

Comment: try the same onBlur function in text box also
`<td> <input type="text" onblur="saveToDatabase(this,'columnName','<?php echo $getData["id"]; ?>')"> </td>`
try this.